# RPG fighting system doesn't work properly

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a RPG fighting system where you would fight a goblin. Unfortunately, the randomizer I'm using to make a luck system doesn't work like I want it to. For some reason the random variable is always the same through each loop when I want it to be a different value each time. I have tried many thing but without success. Also just before posting this here I realized that my while loop doesn't stop when the requirement for it to stop are met.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    std::mt19937 generator;
    generator.seed(std::time(0));

    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> d100(0, 100);

    int random = d100(generator);

    std::mt19937 generator2;
    generator2.seed(std::time(0));

    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> d20(1, 20);

    int random2 = d20(generator2);

    string action;
    int enmyHP = 100;
    int plyrHP = 120;

    while(enmyHP >= 1 || plyrHP >= 1){
        cout << "You are fighting a goblin. What will you do?"<< endl;
        cout << "|| ATTACK ||       || SPELL ||      || RUN ||"<< endl;
        cin >> action;

        if(action == "attack" || action == "Attack" || action == "ATTACK"){
            if(random >= 95){
                cout << "CRITICAL HIT!" << endl;
                cout << "You did 50 damage!" << endl;
                enmyHP - 50;
            } else if(random < 95 && random > 15){
                cout << "You did " << random2 << " damage" << endl;
                enmyHP = enmyHP - random2;
                cout <<"The goblin has: "<< enmyHP << " HP left" << endl;

            } else if(random > 15 && random < 1){
                cout << "You miss" << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "You hit yourself" << endl;
                plyrHP = plyrHP - 20;
                cout << "You have: " << plyrHP << " HP" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do I read it correctly that random and random2 are only set before the loop?

Comment: You're generating your random number outside the loop.

Comment: It looks like you need to get yourself a good book on basic C++. But just to give a hint: don't use multiple engines (your `generator`s), you aren't modifying your `random`s in the loop, and you likely want an AND in your loop condition.

Comment: Please write standard English.

Comment: Did you know exists `std::tolower`?

Comment: Can't find the right dupe now, but please note that seeding two generator with [time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) other then beeing not necessary (you need only one of those mt19937) will almost surely lead to the same sequence, because the granularity of that function is one second.

Answer (score 2):

Here, you are actually generating the random numbers, you are not creating two *dice* with different distributions, so every time you use `random` or `random2` you'll get the same numbers:

```
int random = d100(generator);
int random2 = d20(generator2); // only one generator per thread should usually be used
```

If you'd like to create a set of dice that you could use, you can bind a distribution with a reference to your generator to create a functor, a callable, that you can use like a function. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <iomanip>    // std::setw
#include <functional> // std::bind

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 generator(rd());

    auto d6 = std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<uint16_t>(1, 6), std::ref(generator));
    auto d20 = std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<uint16_t>(1, 20), std::ref(generator));
    auto d100 = std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<uint16_t>(1, 100), std::ref(generator));    
}
```

Alternatively, you could create lambdas to achieve the same effect:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<uint16_t> dist6(1, 6);
std::uniform_int_distribution<uint16_t> dist20(1, 20);
std::uniform_int_distribution<uint16_t> dist100(1, 100);

// capture the distributions and generator by reference
auto d6 = [&](){ return dist6(generator); };
auto d20 = [&](){ return dist20(generator); };
auto d100 = [&](){ return dist100(generator); };
```

**Edit**: As suggested, a you can also make a `Dice` class:

```
class Dice {
    // static is implied below but added to make it clear: one instance
    // is created and shared between instances of Dice.
    //
    // thread_local makes one instance of the variable per thread
    // in case you add mutithreading later.
    static thread_local std::random_device rd;
    static thread_local std::mt19937 generator;

    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> dist;
public:    
    Dice(uint32_t low, uint32_t high) : dist(low, high) {}

    // make instances of the class callable:
    uint32_t operator()() {
        return dist(generator);
    }
};

thread_local std::random_device Dice::rd;
thread_local std::mt19937 Dice::generator = std::mt19937(Dice::rd());

Dice d6(1, 6);
Dice d20(1, 20);
Dice d100(1, 100);
```

Any of the versions can be used like this:

```
while(true) {
    std::cout << d6() << std::setw(3) << d20() << std::setw(4) << d100() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: While your solution is advanced wouldn't it be simpler to just use the distribution directly without bind or lambda's? The user is a beginning C++ programmer as he stated himself.

Comment: I'd suggest wrapping these all up in a `Dice` class

Comment: @gast128 The first part is covered in the explanation and I thought that the fact that OP had made an effort to use `<random>` devices with distributions etc. looked encouraging enough to present an example of how to connect them into ready to use functors.

Comment: @Caleth `Dice` class added